# How can I share the output of an html code written in visual studio code with someone else?

Tags: html

I don't think that we can share the link that we get from the **live server extension** to someone else for viewing our web page.

kindly advise me. I am new to front-end development.

Comment: 1. Please clarify whether the other user is trying to view during the collaborative session or whether you want them to view independently. 2. What does the local link look like, `file:///foo/bar/baz.html` or `http://localhost:3000/foo/bar/baz.html` ? 3. What kind of project is it? Straight HTML or are you generating the HTML from another piece of code?

Answer (score 0):

By default LiveServer will listen for network connections on 127.0.0.1 and is available only to clients running on the same computer.

---

You can change that in the settings (under Live Server > Settings:Host) to specify any IP address allocated to the computer you are working on. You can also use `0.0.0.0` for *every* IP address allocated to that computer.

[image: Screenshot showing the above]

Anyone who can reach the IP address you select (which is typically anyone on the same LAN as you) can then visit `http://192.0.0.10:5500/` to see the site. (Replace the IP address in that example with the one assigned to your computer that you selected above).

For someone to access the server from a different network, you will need to have an IP address on the public Internet. Typically you would get this by following the above instructions and then configuring your router to forward port 5500 from its Internet facing IP address to the IP address of your computer on the LAN.

---

You can also look at tunnelling a connection with by creating an [SSH tunnel manually](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-setup-ssh-tunneling/) or using a service like [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) which connects a URL on the public Internet to your local server (note that this removes the requirement to change the Live Server configuration away from `127.0.0.1`).